# ecc - why does edac-ctl need drivers while edac-util does not?

Tags: linux, ecc

My AMD Ryzen Linux system has ECC memory that purposely bought.

edac-util shows I have ecc, if I am reading correctly:

```
mc0: 0 Uncorrected Errors with no DIMM info
mc0: 0 Corrected Errors with no DIMM info
mc0: csrow0: 0 Uncorrected Errors
mc0: csrow0: mc#0csrow#0channel#0: 0 Corrected Errors
mc0: csrow1: 0 Uncorrected Errors
mc0: csrow1: mc#0csrow#1channel#0: 0 Corrected Errors
mc0: csrow2: 0 Uncorrected Errors
mc0: csrow2: mc#0csrow#2channel#0: 0 Corrected Errors
mc0: csrow3: 0 Uncorrected Errors
mc0: csrow3: mc#0csrow#3channel#0: 0 Corrected Errors
edac-util: No errors to report.
```

But edac-ctl shows drivers not loaded:

```
edac-ctl: drivers not loaded.
```

Why does edac-util not need drivers or recognize drivers while edac-util does?

Note....was not sure if I should ask this here or in linux stack. Since most linux users won't be using ecc I thought I would ask here.

Note 2.... yes, my motherboard supports ECC. I made sure.

Comment: The difference between the sites is: [unix.se] is for general Linux questions. We handle questions with a professional IT context.

Comment: But here is where Linux and ECC would be used together. Unix and Linux would not be using ECC.